# Can't get component from public array of gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could someone explain why I am getting differing results in the output? I am putting in four gameobjects into the "objects" variable, with object1 being the first object in the array. All the objects have the Script component, but when using the array, it refuses to get the component I need.

Btw, I'm using Unity version 2021.1.12f1.

```cs
    public GameObject[] objects = new GameObject[4];
    public GameObject object1;
    private Script script1;
    private Script script2;
    private int index;

    private void Awake()
    {
        script1 = objects[index].GetComponent<Script>();
        script2 = object1.GetComponent<Script>();
        Debug.Log(script1 == null); // outputs "True"
        Debug.Log(script2 == null); // outputs "False"
    }
```

Comment: Did you initialize index?

Comment: Yes, but either way, the default value is 0. objects[index] does not show up to be null.

Comment: Ya. But just not to see any surprises from compilers.

Comment: I believe there couod be a serialization contradiction. If you removed the new GameObject[4] and assigned in inspector, you may fix your issue.

Comment: `Awake` should only be used to initialize the object itself, it shouldn't be used to "talk" to other objects because there's no guarantee of object instantiation at that point. I recommend moving your code to the `Start` event.

Comment: Please include all steps necessary to reproduce the observed behavior.

Comment: Do you actually fill references for objects array in inspector?  Or maybe you fill it up somewhere else programmatically. in that case you should add Script component to new `GameObject` instances before. Also notice that `GameObject` is never created with new keyword but with help of `Instantiate()` method.